# Translated Taxonomy terms in node creation page?

Tags: i18n-l10n, taxonomy-terms

Drupal 7 multilingual website(English and Arabic):

I have a taxonomy term named "Food Category".Added some terms in it.Also i added translation for each terms .

I added a field to select the term in a content type :

LABEL : **Select List Food Category Item**

MACHINE NAME : field_list_items

FIELD TYPE : Term reference

WIDGET : Select list

I want to show the Arabic terms when i translate a node to Arabic.Now it is in English only.

Please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

***admin/config/regional/i18n/select***

```
CONTENT TO FILTER BY LANGUAGE
 Select nodes by language
 Select taxonomy terms by language
```

unselect

> Select taxonomy terms by language